# MongoDB Newsfeed Schema Design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scalability, data-modeling, azure-mobile-services

I am currently developing a **node.js** mobile backend for an **instagram-like** application on Microsoft Azure Mobile Services. I decided to use MongoDB and started coding. But when I read about MongoDB schema designs, I always ending up; "Am I doing right". So thats why I am here.

Diving into technical issue;
Right now I have a simplified **user model** like this ;

```
{  
_id : "userId1" ,  
username : "username",  
following : ["userId2","userId3" ...],  
 }
```

And a simplified **media model** like this;

```
{  
_id : "mediaId" ,  
mediaUrl : "mediaUrl",  
author : { _id : "userId1",  
          userName : "username"
         }  
 }
```

So when I try to get **newsfeed** based on a user, all I should do is retrieve `following` array to get following user ID's and do a query with `$in` operator in media collection by indexed `media.author._id`

The questions are;
**1.** Is this approach **will be a problem** for me when thinking about **million scale**?
**2.** What is the **best available approach** for this case? *( There will be also another aggregation queries based on coordinates, like counts etc. )*
**3.** Right now, my follow architecture is like ; keep the following user ID's as referenced within the user document. Also keep the relation in a collection called follows. *( followeeId, followerId )* is this approach best for this case ?

Third question is optional :P

Greetings and thanks to all of you.
Sercan

Comment: I would recomend that you try your luck on codereview.stackexchange.com, SO (StackOverflow) is dedicated to more specific programming questions.

Comment: I guess you should go thru these 3 links: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 / http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2 / http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3